# Get string after second delimiter VB NET

Tags: string, vb.net, delimiter

I am trying to get the part of the string after the second `/`.
For instance if I have the string `"25/S17/874"`
I would like to get `"874"`
Thanks

Comment: Split the string, look at the resulting array at index 2

Comment: `dim result = somestring.Substring(somestring.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can split the string by `"/"` and the call back from the array.

Example:

```
    Dim string_sample As String
    Dim string_arr As String()
    string_sample = "25/S17/874"
    string_arr = string_sample.Split("/")

    Dim string_Result As String
    string_Result = string_arr(2)
    MsgBox(string_Result)
```

the string_Result is "874"

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim result As String = "25/S17/874".Split("/"c)(2)
```

Obviously, some validation, error trapping, etc might be required if the string content is prone to variation.